# multidimensional array of objects in angular

Tags: c#, arrays, html, angular

I have a multidimensional array of an object in angular 2 declared in my class as follow:

```
export class MatrixComponent implements OnInit {
    private columnsNumber: number = 10;
    private linesNumber: number = 10;
    private grid: SquareComponent [][];

    constructor() {
        this.grid = [];
        var square = new SquareComponent();

        for (var i = 0; i < this.columnsNumber; i++) {
            this.grid[i] = [];

            for (var j = 0; j < this.linesNumber; j++) {
                this.grid[i][j] = new SquareComponent();            
            }
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

using the multidimesional grid array, I want to represent every Square component from the array in the HTML. Something like the follow:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class='table'>        
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of grid[i]">
                <th *ngFor="let column of grid[j]">
                    <app-square></app-square>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Of course the above code doesn't work! I guess the ngFor is used as the foreach is used in C# and what I really need is a normal for loop. I am new to angular and typescript. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet

```
<div class="table-responsive">

    <table class='table'>        
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of grid;let i=index">
                <th *ngFor="let column of row;let j=index">
                    <app-square></app-square>
                    <!-- {{i}}+{{j}} -->
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edypsl?embed=1&file=app/matrix/matrix.component.html)**